# Does using the "new" statement on an already created object cause memory leaks?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I did some research on this question but I haven't really found an answer.

For example, I know that if I wrote this in a game loop:

```
public void update () {
    Object object = new Object();
}
```

Then I would have a memory leak.

But if you have a class object you are calling `new` on, it wouldn't cause a memory leak, right? Since you aren't creating another object, you're just giving the current object a new value.

For example:

```
private Object object;

//...

public void update () {
    object = new Object();
}
```

-Edit

Thanks for your help! I now see that I pretty much had no clue what a memory leak is or what causes it... But I understand more now than I did before!

Comment: "Then I would have a memory leak." That's not true. You would only have a memory leak if you held on to the reference object once that method finished, otherwise it would just be GC'd.

Comment: The `new value` is a new object

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Clear text, please.

Comment: `[teach-me]` You have a lot of misconceptions. You mix up a variable and object (variable is a reference to an object). Java has no "class variables" and `Object` is a class, not any kind of variable. Memory leak in Java is very different from that in C or C++. You're not calling `new` on anything, `new` is an expression(operator?) that creates an instance of the given class. Please forget all you know about Java and start with a decent tutorial. If you're learning Java in a college/school, you need a lot of help from your professor/teacher.

Comment: I see! I guess I didn't quite understand what a memory leak was in the first place! Thanks for you guy's help! As for mixing up a variable and an object, that was just a stupid mistake. I completely understand the difference between the two, I just wasn't thinking!

Comment: But, on the other hand, I'm always willing to use any good Java classes I can find! Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise of your question is flawed.

You *never* call new *on* an already-created object. You call new, and you always (by specification) get a new object (or something like an exception or error occurs).

What you are asking about here is assigning them to a variable or a field. In and of itself, it makes no difference whether it is a variable or a field from a memory leak perspective. It also makes no difference whether this field or variable is also initialized: you are just replacing a reference to one object with a reference to another.

The only thing which would make a difference is if you *also* add the object to a List (or some other collection, array etc), or add the object which contains the field to a List etc: then, it would not be possible to garbage collect, since the object is still reachable. Then you would have a memory leak.

Comment: *It makes absolutely no difference whether it is a variable or a field from a memory leak perspective.* - somewhat disagree. With local variable in the method it is immediately obvious that there's no memory leak. Not so obvious with the field.

Comment: @lexicore the memory leak would only arise if you assign to a field *and* hold on to the thing which contains the field, or you otherwise hold on to the reference, as I state in the last paragraph. Assigning it to the field in and of itself is not a cause of a memory leak. Assigning it to a local variable does not prevent a memory leak.

Comment: I think "hold onto *unnecessarily*" would be the criteria.  There are lots of cases where I want to hold on to a reference but it's not a memory leak.

Comment: I understand now, I'm glad I asked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

None of the examples are memory leaks. No memory is lost. The garbage collector will reclaim the memory as there are no references to it. Both examples allocate memory, though. Every time you call new it allocates a new object. It doesn't matter if you store the new object somewhere or not. So in both cases this would be bad in a tight loop as it would allocate memory, which must then be garbage collected.

As a side note Java is quite smart, so it may well optimize away both examples after a while if they are in a tight loop as you are not using the values. To avoid that (if you really want slow code) make the variable volatile.